# add routes after login page for user

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, routes, dashboard

I use backpack 4 for laravel(laravel 8)and can't write a route for the user page. After login user has to get /user/dashboard or /dashboard, but the user is redirected to /admin/dashboard. How can I solve this problem?

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect()->route('backpack.auth.login');
});
Route::get('/user/dashboard', [DashboardUserController::class, 'index'])->middleware(['web','admin']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your users won't ever need to use Backpack and should only able to view the dashboard, you could add a new middleware to Backpack's set of middlewares that checks if your user is an admin or a normal user to redirect them if they are not an admin.

Because Backpack registers the login routes itself, you can't just add your middleware to the route on registration. Instead you'll need to add your middleware to Backpack's `admin` middleware group. That's the one that gets added to all admin routes.

Steps:

1. Create the new middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware RedirectToDashboard
```

2. Open the new middleware at `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectToDashboard.php`
3. Change the `handle` method to look something like this:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->user()->isNormalUser()) { // You need to change this to the check if the user is a normal user, that's specific to your application
        return redirect()->to('dashboard'); // 'dashboard' is the name of your route, you may need to change it.
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

4. Add the new middleware to Backpack's default set of middlewares in `config/backpack/base.php`. Open the file and look for the `middleware_class` entry (most likely somewhere around line 220). Add `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectToDashboard::class` to the array.
5. Log into Backpack as a normal user and check if you get redirected.

Comment: I have done it, but I get this error:Error
Call to a member function isNormalUser() on null

Comment: You need to change the method to use your logic to determine if your user is a normal user or an admin.

Answer (score 1):

The `/admin` prefix comes from the file: `config/backpack/base.php`.
Remove `route_prefix` from the file.

Your users will be redirected to `/dashboard`.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try clear config and routes cache